# Javascript: Can't print object property defined by Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, object

I use `Object.defineProperty` method to define a property of an object:

```
const o = { a: 1 }
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  get() {
    return this.a
  }, set(value) {
    this.a = value
  }
})
```

However, when I am using `console.log` try to print object `o`, the `b` property seem not in it.

But when I try to use `o.b` to access to it, it can return correct value

So I am confused: why the property can't be printed but can be accessed?

Answer (score 1):

Properties added with [`.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) are by default *non-enumerable*.

Make them "visible" by setting `enumerable: true`

```js
var foo = {}
Object.defineProperty(foo, "a", {
  get() { return "a"; }
});

Object.defineProperty(foo, "b", {
  get() { return "b"; },
  enumerable: true
});

console.log(Object.keys(foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have own enumerable properties and all own properties of an object.

To get all enumerable own properties, you could take [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and for getting the non-enumerable properties as well, you coul take [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).

Maybe `console.log` shows only the enumerable properties of an object. This implementation is up to the vendor.

```js
const o = { a: 1 }
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  get() {
    return this.a
  }, set(value) {
    this.a = value
  }
})

console.log(o);
console.log(Object.keys(o));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get propertyNames using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```js
const o = { a: 1 }
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  get() {
    return this.a
  }, set(value) {
    this.a = value
  }
})

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o))
```